# How to use docker in github workflows to build archlinux package?

Tags: linux, docker, github-actions

In local it works with Dockerfile:

```
FROM archlinux:latest
RUN pacman -Syu make cmake gcc base-devel --noconfirm
RUN useradd build
```

and bash:

```
cmake  CMakeLists.txt
cmake --build .
makepkg
```

run with

```
docker build -t build .
docker run -v "$PWD" --user build -w "/app" build ./build.sh
```

In local all works fine, but with github worklows

```
name: archlinux build
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build
      run: docker build -t build . && docker run -v "$PWD" --user build -w "/app" build ./build.sh
```

job failed with error:

```
CMake Error: Unable to (re)create the private pkgRedirects directory:
/app/CMakeFiles/pkgRedirects
Error: could not load cache
==> ERROR: You do not have write permission for the directory $BUILDDIR (/app).
    Aborting...
```

I tried to check what the problem is with creating files, and instead of cmake I inserted `touch test`. The touch also refuses to run due to access problems. How to make it possible that files in github workflow can be created inside the docker container?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the workflow was running as the user's root, and makepkg required a different user. Replaced run with ./ci_build.sh, which added chmod, and it all worked.
ci_build.sh:

```
   chmod 777 . -R 
   docker build -t build . && docker run -v "$PWD" --user build -w "/app"
   build ./build.sh
```